# "Мало_взаимосвязанные" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, слитно-раздельно

> Два мало_взаимосвязанных раздела

Слитно или раздельно пишется "мало_взаимосвязанных"?

Answer (score 2):

Пишется раздельно. Мало - наречие.

Answer (score 2):

**Ответ @olsa корректен.**

Пример: Объединение в новом учебном курсе двух **мало взаимосвязанных разделов** было во многом обусловлено наибольшим развитием в данный период бухгалтерской науки

**Замечания по другому ответу**

1. ***Малосольные*** огурцы пишутся слитно, так как нет слова "сольные".
2. Наречие ***"мало"*** хотя и часто, но не всегда пишется слитно с прилагательными, например: отрасли народного хозяйства, **мало продвинутые** в научно-техническом отношении. Часто встречаются парные написания: ***малоосвещенный и мало освещенный***.
3. **[В орфографическом словаре](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=71) РАН** нет слова "маловзаимосвязанный".
4. **В [словаре Лопатина](https://gufo.me/dict/orthography_lopatin)** (Слитно, раздельно или через дефис) также нет этого слова.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется вы ошибаетесь) Раздельно если чего-то взаимосвязанных мало) слитно - если речь о чем то маловзаимосвязаном между собой, разве нет? Иначе у меня вопросы к малосольным огурцам, ведь мало-наречие, пишется раздельно))))

Два маловзаимосвязанных раздела